# How to write flume custom sink and source in version 1.3.1

Tags: flume

I am trying to write my own sink and source in flume version 1.3.It doesn't have config file flume-site.xml. How could I use this custom sink after I compile my java file?

Answer (score 4):

You need to put jar with your compiled sink somewhere to flume CLASSPATH. In version 1.3.1, simply lib/ should be sufficient. For newer version you will have option to use "plugins.d" directory, checkout FLUME-1735 [1] for more details (fixed in trunk and will be part of 1.4.0).

To configure flume to actually use your sink, use fully qualified name of your class (e.g. package.ClassName) in the configuration. For example if your class is in package "earth.europe" and the class name is "WorldSink", then you need to use following configuration fragment:

```
a1.sinks = s1
a1.sinks.s1.type = earth.europe.WorldSink
```

Jarcec

Links:

1: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLUME-1735